# SciPy : Issue passing options to local minimizer in optimize.shgo

Tags: python, scipy, parameter-passing, scipy-optimize, shgo

I am trying to use the SHGO algorithm from SciPy and I would like to change the maximum number of iterations of the local minimizer.
To do so I have added the argument `minimizer_kwargs = {'options':{'maxiter':200}}` to the `shgo` function.
This the display of the local minimizer :

```
lres =  message: Iteration limit reached
 success: False
  status: 9
     fun: 26.05582140171688
       x: [ 1.217e+02 -1.441e-01  1.302e-01  3.260e-01]
     nit: 100
     jac: [-1.317e-02  2.812e+01  0.000e+00  1.173e+02]
    nfev: 1461
    njev: 100
```

The optimization stopped because of maximum iteration reached and `nit` is 100 which is the default value as if the `maxiter` option has not been taken into account.

To have a clearer idea of the issue I have run the cattle-feed example and tried to limit the iterations number of the local minimizer to 2.

```
import scipy
import numpy as np

print('SciPy version :', scipy.__version__)

def f(x):  # (cattle-feed)
    return 24.55*x[0] + 26.75*x[1] + 39*x[2] + 40.50*x[3]

def g1(x):
    return 2.3*x[0] + 5.6*x[1] + 11.1*x[2] + 1.3*x[3] - 5  # >=0

def g2(x):
    return (12*x[0] + 11.9*x[1] +41.8*x[2] + 52.1*x[3] - 21
            - 1.645 * np.sqrt(0.28*x[0]**2 + 0.19*x[1]**2
                            + 20.5*x[2]**2 + 0.62*x[3]**2)) # >=0

def h1(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] - 1  # == 0

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': g1},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': g2},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': h1})

bounds = [(0, 1.0),]*4

res = scipy.optimize.shgo(f, bounds, n=150, constraints=cons,
           minimizer_kwargs = {'options':{'maxiter':2}},
           options={'disp':True})
```

which returns :

```
SciPy version : 1.10.1
Splitting first generation
Starting minimization at [1.000 1.000 0.000 0.000]...
bounds in kwarg:
[[0.5, 1.0], [0.5, 1.0], [0.0, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5]]
lres =  message: Positive directional derivative for linesearch
 success: False
  status: 8
     fun: 33.64749052456115
       x: [ 5.000e-01  5.000e-01  8.055e-02  1.199e-01]
     nit: 8
     jac: [ 2.455e+01  2.675e+01  3.900e+01  4.050e+01]
    nfev: 20
    njev: 4
Starting minimization at [0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000]...
bounds in kwarg:
[[0.0, 0.5], [0.0, 0.5], [0.5, 1.0], [0.0, 0.5]]
lres =  message: Optimization terminated successfully
 success: True
  status: 0
     fun: 31.77500000000491
       x: [ 5.000e-01  1.835e-13  5.000e-01  0.000e+00]
     nit: 2
     jac: [ 2.455e+01  2.675e+01  3.900e+01  4.050e+01]
    nfev: 10
    njev: 2
Successfully completed construction of complex.
```

As you can see the first local minimization reaches 8 iterations so the `maxiter` option has not been considered and it is the same result as if `minimizer_kwargs = {'options':{'maxiter':2}}` was omitted.

Am I doing or understanding something wrong when trying to change the options of the local minimizer or should this approach work ?

(I also tried `'disp':True` in the options and it also did nothing).

Comment: As I found in the documentation I think this method accept both arguments `minimizer_kwargs` and `option`. Did you try to pass `scipy.optimize.shgo(f, bounds, n=150, constraints=cons, options={'maxiter':2})`?